# Menu mobile height completo

Tags: html, css

Quero que o menu mobile o background dele preto, fique com `height` completo.

Aqui esta meu código:

```
 #sidebar {
  position:fixed;

  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  width:45%;
  height:100%;
  background:#1a1a1a;
  text-align:center;
  transform-origin:right;
  transform:perspective(1200px) rotateY(90deg);
  transition:all 400ms ease;
  z-index: 2000;
  font-family:'Lora', serif;
```

Aqui está o site caso precise:
http://lancamento.99gourmet.com.br/

Comment: Não coloque o titulo em caixa alta. O que quer dizer com `height` completo ? Que a altura do menu não passe a altura da página ?

Comment: Não consegui abrir o site, e sem o HTML para eu ver o problema é mais complicado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #sidebar {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  width:45%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%
  min-height:100%;
  background:#1a1a1a;
  text-align:center;
  transform-origin:right;
  transform:perspective(1200px) rotateY(90deg);
  transition:all 400ms ease;
  z-index: 2000;
  font-family:'Lora', serif;
```

Caso não funcione.. será necessário colocar um valor fixo para o height!